# How do you use [RequireHttps] in a Rackspace Cloud Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ssl, rackspace-cloud

I am trying to use [RequireHttps] in Rackspace Cloud Site, but I am just getting a redirect loop message when I hit any actions that use the attribute.  I have talk to support, but they are not much help.  Has anyone got [RequireHttps] working in a MVC 3 site on rackspace cloud sites?

Comment: Found a solution that fixed my issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093858/check-for-ssl-when-hosted-in-rackspace-mosso-cloud

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem. I finally found a knowledge base article on Rackspace's site.

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-force-ssl-on-my-aspnet-site-on-cloud-sites

The web.config option worked just fine, just be sure to remove the [RequireHttps] attribute from your code (it isn't needed).

I have copied it below for simplicity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_CLUSTER_HTTPS}" pattern="^on$" negate="true" />
          <add input="{HTTP_CLUSTER_HTTPS}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{SCRIPT_NAME}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
     </rule>
   </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```